# Using a negative number with a CurrencyFormatter in swit 4

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting

I have a currency format func that looks like this:

```
func currencyFormat() -> NumberFormatter{
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
    // localize to your grouping and decimal separator
    currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    return currencyFormatter
}
```

So when I use it like this:

```
currencyFormat().string(for: 20.34)   --> $20.34
```

Same goes if I send over a negative value

```
currencyFormat().string(for: -20.34)  -->  -$20.34
```

I don't want the negative sign to come back formatted with the currency

It works great but the issue I'm having is if I send it a negative decimal number, I get back the negative sign. Is there a way to drop that sign? Should I convert the decimal to positive before I send it over to the converter?

Comment: Can you provide some more code, with sample example, what exact you have issue..?

Comment: What is your desired behavior? `-500` becomes `$500`?

Comment: You need to clarify your issue. The code you posted doesn't do anything except create a formatter. Show code that actually demonstrates your issue. Show the exact output of `print` statements showing your actual results and clearly indicate your desired results.

Comment: *"Should I convert the decimal to positive before I send it over to the converter?"* – Yes, that is a simple and clean solution. Setting `currencyFormatter.minusSign = ""` is more of a hack.

Comment: @Paolo, yes that is what I would like to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the number is positive before sending it through the currency formatter by taking the absolute value:

```
let number = -500
let positiveNumber = abs(number)

let formattedNumber = currencyFormat().string(for: positiveNumber)
```

This is the simplest and most readable way to do it.

Comment: What if the number is a NSDecimalNumber?

Comment: @icekomo You can get the value as a `Double` by doing `number.doubleValue`

Comment: @icekomo: If your input is a NSDecimalNumber then please tell us so in the question. Your example uses `Double` only.

Comment: @Martin, I wasn't using a double, but was curious for future reference that's all. I didn't think a small thing like that warranted another question.